# Is it possible to configure Apache-Tomcat with specific number of cores?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, multi-core, perfomance

Is it possible to configure an Apache Tomcat (v7) with an specific number of cores? How can I specify it?

I'm developing in a machine with 4 cores, but when uploading to the server with 8 cores, the perfomances increases a 800%. I need to check if the numbers of cores used is the responsible of it.

Relevant data:

- Server: Apache Tomcat (v7.0.47)
- OS: Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

With systemd, in unit file you can: set

1. `CPUAffinity` which controls cores used: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html
2. `CPUQuota` to limit CPU utilization: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

also, there are options for setting process priority.

For non-systemd, you can use `taskset` for affinity settings: https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset